# How to simulate buffers (ABT) in ltspice

Tags: ltspice

I would like to simulate this buffer in LTspice [74ABT244PW](https://www.nexperia.com/products/analog-logic-ics/asynchronous-interface-logic/buffers-inverters-drivers/74ABT244PW.html). I already got its model under the "support" section of the link. Now I'm new to LTspice and I had experience adding models before but how I did it in the past I first add a base component and make a directive from the external then link the base component to the directive. But now there is no buffer in the component list.

[image]

So how do I simulate that buffer component?

Comment: Have you tried searching for the part itself (maybe LTSpice doesn't support too many logic chips?)

Comment: @Andyaka No 74abT244 showed up when i type it in the search box of the image in the question. Are there other ways to search components im not aware of?

Comment: You can probably choose an AC version or HC version and tweak the timings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Their page](https://www.nexperia.com/products/analog-logic-ics/asynchronous-interface-logic/buffers-inverters-drivers/74ABT244PW.html) has an archive with a SPICE model (*not* the IBIS one). In it there are two folders, `HSpice` and `PSpice` -- the latter is the one you're looking for, since LTspice is, mostly, PSpice compatible.

Inside there are a few library files (`*.lib`) containing lots of subcircuit definitions, many of them being used inside the actual model for the gate. It can look daunting, but there is also an `abtps.cir` file, which is a test circuit that can be readily opened up in LTspice, and simulated. It has no *visual* schematic because it's nothing but a netlist, but it does list the possible `.lib` combinations you need in order to build you own schematic, including some other files.

In this case, it shows that in order to use the `74ABT244` you need to add:

- the ABT family library with `.lib abtpsub.lib`;
- the relevant package -- choose between `lib so.s`, `.lib ssop.s`, or `.lib tssop.s`;
- the default parameters with `.lib abtpnom.lib`, or the fast ones (`abtpfas.lib`) or slow ones (`abtpslw.lib`). The differences should be in the level of detail with which the device is made at transistor-level. The nominal should do.

I don't know what and how you did it, but if you say you see no symbol it's because there is none included; you'll need to create one, yourself. Or autogenerate one, if it's to your liking.

One thing to notice: the test file (`abtps.cir`) uses a global net, `$G_VCC`, inside their subcircuits. Since you say you're new to this, a net name that starts with `$G_` means it's global and is available at any level in a hierarchy, or subcircuits (i.e. here, `$G_VCC` used inside the libraries will be available at the "surface", or in the top level schematic); otherwise, labels are only available to the current level (i.e. a node named `X` inside a subcircuit will not be visible outside of it, and using the same `X` notation outside the subcircuit will not clash with the subcircuit one). I'm saying this to be careful when using that name.

So, for your case, here's one way to use the GUI to replicate their test file:

[image: test]

I haven't created any symbol, manually or autogenerated; instead, I used the readily available `[Misc]/tetrode`, because it already has 4 pins. If you look in their test circuit, the relevant line for the subcircuit is:

```
XABT244       2       4       $G_VCC      0       BUFFER2
```

so any symbol with 4 pins will do. The order of the pins is input, output, positive supply, and negative supply -- that's how you see it now connected. But, since their test doesn't use a symbol (a netlist doesn't need one), you can circumvent that by adding a SPICE directive (<kbd>S</kbd> key) with the line that you see commented out, above (in blue text); that will substitute the need for a symbol.

Another difference is their usage of `$G_VCC`. I avoided that to show that it's not mandatory to use it, since my power supply uses, simply, `VCC`. But the availablility of `$G_VCC` remains, and if I were to connect something else with that node, it would interfere with the symbol -- so, be careful!

About the last difference would be the usage of the simulation card: `.TRAN 500p 50n` vs my `.TRAN 50n`. The former notation makes use of the legacy way of defining the simulation command (you can see it in the LTspice's help: *LTspice > Dot Commands > .TRAN*). In short, the `500p` should add a hint to the solver about the timestep that should be used, but, as the manual says:

> The first form is the traditional .tran SPICE command. Tstep is the plotting increment for the waveforms but is also used as an initial step-size guess. LTspice uses waveform compression, **so this parameter is of little value and can be omitted or set to zero**.

Emphasis mine. Therefore I used the latter form.

---

Alternatively, if all you need is some digital buffer, I'd recommend `[Digital]/buf`, or `[Digital]/inv`, `[Digital]/schmitt`, or `[Digital]/schmittinv`. See the help under *LTspice > Circuit Elements > A. [...]* for more settings.

Comment: To add the library i need the ltspice file to be in the same folder as the library? Also how did you navigate to find the tetrode? I actually need to simulate this specific IC as this is the one i will use, i need to simulate the 4 channel in parralell. How to do that? do i just make 4 copies of the tetrode in your circuit?

Comment: I think i have everything inplace, but im lost on how to link the tetrode the model. [Image](https://i.ibb.co/7bg1x9w/image.png)

Comment: Okay i was able to simulate, Quick question why is the output voltage so low? that does not feel right

Comment: @DrakeJest The datasheet specifies the minimum output logic high to be 3 V (for Io=3 mA, and here it's ~6 mA after the cap is charged, and 120 mA peak). Since the load is 500 Ohms, that is quite a high load, which means that 3.5 V that you see there can be very real. Of course, the actual output can only be verified on the breadboard, and any simulation is only as good as the models they use. Don't forget that the specs between samples can differ, too.

Comment: I have 4 in parallel in my setup so im expecting a bit higher voltage, weird paralleling 4 of the buffers seems to have no effect.

Comment: None the less thank you for your help :) I simulating made me second guess in choosing this IC (which is good)

Comment: @DrakeJest That's not what I see. Using only one shows a peak voltage of 3.6 V. Using 4 in parallel shows 4 V peak. So there's definitely an improvement. How are you testing this? Are you still using a *series* RC, as in the picture from your comment, above? Are you still using 500 Ohms as the load? What load do you need? For what purpose? Is it resistive, or capacitive, or inductive? It's better to either open up a new question, or think about them yourself -- I'd recommend the latter. Solving it yourself will not only give you wings, but chances are you'll always remember this.

Comment: I saved the project and restarted ltspice, after that i am seeing the changes. I guess ltspice can be buggy at times.

Comment: @DrakeJest It doesn't make sense. All subcircuits are loaded on a need basis. There must have been something else you did. I've been using LTspice for more than 15 years and I can say with a quite high certainty that it's one of the most robust programs I've used. At any rate, it seems it solved your problem.

Comment: its most probably just me doing something wrong. Thank you very much for the help. With what the simulation is showing i can conclude that this IC is not for me, it just too close to 3.8v required to register a HIGH. I have done some test with my setup and an arduino uno's gpio with no buffer or anything performs better than this.